# Mac Book Pro - View movie while keyboard disabled?

Tags: macbook-pro, mac

I have a toddler that wants to push all the keys while watching a video or movie. Can I disable the keyboard while he is watching it? OR Is there a hard snap on cover that can go over the keyboard and trac pad?

Comment: Did you find any good answers to this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [KeyboardCleanTool](http://blog.boastr.net/?s=keyboardcleantool) (download in upper right). I just searched everywhere and it seems to be the only tool for Mac that does this exact thing for free and is still available. I just did a quick test and it seems to work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

As someone who has had personal experience putting keys back on after a toddler ripped them out, I would highly suggest simplifying matters and buying one of those neoprene sleeves ([found here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001D8J7CA) -- make sure you get the right size) for your notebook, and put the bottom section of your notebook inside the case, while still leaving the display visible.